# Why would a session variable be missing after a Postback?

Tags: c#, session

I'm having an issue with a session variable going missing after a user presses the next page button on the gridview.  I see that the session is set when first loading up the gridview with data, but when the user presses the button to the next page.  The session that is holding the data is missing.  Has anybody else had this issue?

Comment: What are you using? Also please provide code you're using.

Comment: Can you let us know hiow are you accessing the session variable?

Comment: Here is the code for saving the session.  private void saveSearchResults(List<CourseSearchResult> results)
        {
            if(ViewState[sessionName] == null)
                Session.Add(sessionName, results);
            else
                Session[sessionName] = results;
        } 
Then here is the code to get the variable

 var results = Session[sessionName] == null ? null : Session[sessionName] as List<CourseSearchResult>;

I always thought the session will always available even after a postback.  I'm incorrect on this assumption?